# Any API to extract all the page titles from Wikipedia for a specific language [Python 2.7]

Tags: python-2.7, api, wikipedia

Is there any API to extract all the page titles from Wikipedia for a specific language?

Comment: You really should change the image to include different titles - its text isn't at all suitable for this site.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to get the list of titles is to download it from the [latest Wikipedia dump](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/). You probably want `enwiki-latest-all-titles-in-ns0.gz` (all titles of pages in the article namespace, including redirects and disambiguation pages) or `enwiki-latest-all-titles.gz` (all titles in all namespaces). These are just newline-separated text files, so after you have uncompressed them they will be easy to parse in your language of choice.

The Wikimedia Foundation also make database dumps for other language Wikipedias and for their other projects, like Wiktionary and Wikibooks. For example, you can find the dumps for the Spanish Wikipedia by clicking on "eswiki" at the [database dumps list](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/backup-index.html).

It is also possible to get lists of pages via the action API, using something like [/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=allpages](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=allpages). However, there may be a lot of articles to parse. For example, the English Wikipedia has 5.4 million articles, so if you try to use the action API to get a list of all of the English Wikipedia's article titles, and you use the default number of return pages (10), you would need to send 540,000 requests to get the whole list. That might take you a while. ;)

You can use the [API sandbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox) to play around with different API parameters, if you're interested. See the [API manual](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page) for detailed documentation.

Comment: I downloaded enwiki-latest-all-titles-in-ns0.gz.  It is about 16M uncompressed of text.  But it does not say what is the title page and what redirects to those pages!!! 
enwiki-latest-all-titles.gz uncompressed is huge!  about 1.5 Gig.  It is two column and I am guessing with the first column being 0 for the pages (see wikipedia namespaces).  That should give titles of pages.  I am guessing he ones whose frist column is not 0 are not the wikipedia titles.  Again no redirects.

Comment: If you need to find which ones are redirects, you can download one of the database dumps and try to parse it. The database dumps have all of the public-facing info, so it is definitely possible to get redirect status of the pages. (I think there is a specific column for redirect status, if memory serves correctly.) Parsing dumps is an art, though, so you should search for other resources on this first.

Comment: Also, the number in the first column of enwiki-latest-all-titles.gz will be the namespace number. That is 0 for pages in the main namespace, 1 for the "Talk" namespace, 2 for "User" namespace, and so on. You can see more info at [Manual:Namespace](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Namespace) on mediawiki.org.

Comment: If you want to filter the list of pages, you can make a query on db, no need to parse it. https://quarry.wmcloud.org/